# Sequence and multiplicity of sums of integers squared $n_1^2+n_2^2+\dots+n_d^2$?

Tags: sequences-and-series, summation

Consider a summation over $d$ integers such as

$$R_d=\sum_{n_1,n_2,\dots,n_d\in\mathbb{Z}}f\left(\sum_{i=1}^d n_i^2\right)$$

Is there a way to express this sum in terms of a specific integer sequence $S$, such that

$$R_d = \sum_{n\in S}M_n f(n)$$

with term multiplicity $M_n$?

What is the sequence $S$ and the multiplicity $M_n$ given by in this case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$M_n$ is the [sum of squares function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sum_of_squares_function). Of course one could simply say that $S$ consists of all nonnegative integers but that $M_n$ sometimes equals $0$; however, the exact set $S$ for which $M_n$ is positive is known for each $d$:

- When $d=1$, $S$ is the set of perfect squares of course.
- When $d=2$, [it follows from theorems of Brahmagupta–Fibonacci and Fermat](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sum_of_two_squares_theorem) that $S$ is the set of integers all of whose prime factors that are $3\pmod4$ occur with even multiplicity.
- When $d=3$, [Legendre showed](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legendre%27s_three-square_theorem) that $S$ is the set of all integers not equal to a power of $4$ times an integer congruent to $7\pmod8$.
- When $d\ge4$, [Jacobi showed](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jacobi%27s_four-square_theorem) that $S$ is the entire set of nonnegative integers.